# Natural join of table (A) with itself

Tags: mysql, join, relational-algebra, natural-join

I came across this question in an interview and I have been wondering if what I did was right. Let's say I have a table 'A' with the following attributes:

```
R   S    T
-----------
a1  b1   c1
a1  b2   c2
a1  b3   c3
a4  b4   c4
```

and lets say I need to calculate the Relational Algebra for given B = {[(projection)R,S (A) NATURAL JOIN (projection) S,T (A) ] NATURAL JOIN (projection)R,T (A)}

what would be the result?

### This is what I tried:

```
-We know (A) NATURAL JOIN (A) = A
-I did the first set of join within the square bracket. Since we had  attribute 'S' in common I just yielded the result to be a table of (R S T) with the same 4 rows of tuples.
-Finally, I joined (R S T) with the second set of join where attributes 'R' and 'T' are common which I assumed will yield R S T again with 4 rows of tuples.
```

Meaning, with the way I did it, I ended up getting B = A.

I did not consider the tuples at all, I just did a natural join based on the common attributes between two projections.

I know that's very stupid.. but I am trying to execute it in MySQL and for some reason I am getting errors when I try to execute such a query:

select A,B from dbt2.relationalalgebra as r1 NATURAL JOIN (select B, C from dbt2.relationalalgebra as r2); and I am getting an error saying every derived table must have its own aliases!

Please help me clarify on how Natural join works on same table.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is correct. And it's correct that you obtained B = A -- given that content for A.

This is a question about the functional dependencies between the values in the data. (So you might not get B = A, if the data was different.)

For attributes S and T, there's a different value in each tuple. IoW given a value for S (or T), you know which row it's from, so you know the value for the other two attributes in that tuple. The functional dependencies are S -> R, T; T -> R, S. (You might say that S or T are each keys for A.)

The pairs of attributes in the projections you give each include at least one key, so uniquely determine which 'missing' attribute gets joined. You're seeing a lossless join decomposition, as per Heath's Theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency

Answer (score 0):

A natural join is a shorthand for joining two tables (or subqueries) on all columns that have the same name.

A natural join of a table to itself could have several consequences.  The most common would be the table itself -- if none of the values are NULL and the rows are unique.  If each row had a `NULL` value in some column, then the `natural join` would return no rows at all.  If rows are duplicated, then multiple rows might appear.

I do not recommend ever using `natural join`.  A small change to an underlying table structure could break a query.

Comment: This is a question about Relational Algebra, not SQL. You've provided an excellent reason why SQL's NULL is an abomination -- which is why it doesn't appear in the RA. The OP states quite correctly that (A) NATURAL JOIN (A) = A. That is not necessarily the case with SQL (because of the problem of NULLs). I do not recommend ever using SQL.